# Python Shell says I have version 3.6 but terminal says I have 2.7

Tags: python, conda

`which python` returns: 
`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python`

When I open my shell, the first couple lines of the shell read: 
`Python 3.6.8 (v3.6.8:3c6b436a57, Dec 24 2018, 02:04:31) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.`

And finally, the issue is that when I am in my shell and I try to import pandas (which is installed), I receive `no module named 'pandas'`. Which, according to [this article](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11604), is due to having multiple installations of Python and running Python from the system.

The solution proposed by the aforementioned article is to use conda. But, will simply installing conda solve my issue of my shell returning something different from terminal? I am really new to programming so assume I don't know how any of this works!

Comment: I assume that by "open my shell" you just type `python` on the command line - not jupyter notebook or other IDE. In the shell, does `sys.executable` match `which python`?

Comment: By shell, I mean I open Python IDLE. And in the shell, when I run `sys exectuable`, a different version is returned: `'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6'`

Comment: Using `python3` and `pip3` may solve your problem. Is this an older MAC? Up until recently mac/linux tended to use python 2 for their own scripts. You could install python 3 and (at least in the cases I've seen) use it as `python3` and `pip3`. One of the better options is to create a virtual environment for your pandas install. You may even be able to install python 3.8 from your OS repo and use that. See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html#creating-virtual-environments

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't import pandas in your shell is because you installed it into a different a python. You can install it to the python you need via the `pip.exe` from the python you need. The reason you can `import pandas` after installing `anaconda` is because installing `anaconda` will install many modules with it, like `numpy`, `scipy`, `sympy`, etc.

Comment: what would the full code for `pip.exe` look like, to install panda within the correct  Python version? And do I do this in the command line or in Python IDLE?

Comment: You go to your command line, cd to the folder where the pip for the right python is, then use the command *pip install pandas*

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing a cleanup of your python environment for your Mac.

You can first find out what python do you have by typing the following in your terminal:

```
which -a python
```

In my case I have:

```
/Users/.../anaconda3/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
```

Anaconda python3 and the default python2. In your case, since you had a python3.6.8, it must be installed somewhere and you should be able to see it from the above command.

Now there are 2 options:

1. You can continue using that python3.6.8 by adding that to your environment path. According to your description, seems like your default is python3.6.8, you probably used wrong pip to install pandas. Maybe instead of `pip`, use `pip3`.
2. You can delete where your python3.6.8 is, and then install anaconda. When you are installing anaconda, it takes care of everything including setting your environment. So that most likely you won't accidentally use any of your other python installations anymore. The defaults will be set to anaconda python. You can continue to use `pip` to install packages, or you can use `conda install` which comes with anaconda installation. You can also install miniconda, which is a light-weight version of anaconda that only comes with default most basic packages. This way you will have a better control of your python packages. But if you are new, you can safely go for the full anaconda distribution.

Comment: When I do the above command (`which -a python`), I only see `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python` and not the 3.6 version I have in Python IDLE.

Comment: Sometimes they do not explicitly label it as python3.x but just use python as name (just like my anaconda). Probably usr/local/bin/python is the python3.6 version, can you check it by running that `/usr/local/bin/python` in your terminal? This will activate this specific python kernel.